# Increasing Kernel Mode Setting (KMS) scrollback buffer size

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, kms

I'm using Kernel Mode Setting to set my server's `tty` resolution.

I added `GRUB_GFXMODE=1280x1024x24,auto` to `/etc/default/grub`, and `GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep` was already there.  There's no `vga=` or `nomodeset`.

I ran `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` and rebooted.

I also want to increase the scrollback buffer.  I've read `fbcon=scrollback:XXXk` shouldn't be used because KMS is better than `fbcon`.

What's the new proper way to do this, using KMS?

Answer (score 0):

fbcon works with a KMS backing device, there's no difficulty here at all.  I would reconsider the accuracy of your anonymous source.

They may have been thinking of kmscon.  If you're actually using kmscon then it has its own docs / manual page which *will* answer this question for you.

Note kmscon was a bit of an experiment by the author.  If we're looking at wider adoption, I think the equivalent that's in the systemd tree, written by the same author, is the more obvious choice.  The name of this equivalent does not include kms, iirc.